# Use variable for column in dplyr's group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write a little top_n_by function in dplyr.

```
topNby = function(df, dim, byDim, n) {
  return( group_by(df, as.symbol(dim)) %>%
          summarise(topDim = sum(byDim)) %>%
          arrange(desc(topDim)) %>% 
          slice(1:n) %>%
          .[[dim]] %>% as.character() 
          )
}
```

But `group_by` throw back an error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'yourDim' not found
```

I also tried without `as.symbol` but with no success. What is the correct way to use `group_by` when you want to be able to dynamically set the column(s) of grouping.

(I am pretty sure this must have been answered elsewhere but cannot find a satisfying answer...)

Comment: Did you try with `group_by_` (notice the added underscore)?

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! With and without `as.symbol`! Any idea on where to find doc on this? Shall we just always use `group_by_` or do certain scenario require `group_by`.

The doc is pretty minimal : http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/functions/group_by

Comment: I think it's in the vignettes somewhere.  I'll see if I can find it

Comment: See this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found that I also needed `summarise_` !

Comment: By the way, the doc `?summarise_` refers you to the vignette in describing its `.dots` argument.